# Unable to run python - pyodbc in aws lamdba

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

unable to execute pyodbc in the aws lamdba

Error on the AWS Lamdba.

[image]

This is the python code.

```
        import requests  
        import pyodbc as po
        
        server = '*****'
        database = '*****'
        username = '*****'
        password = '******'
        
        def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
        cnxn = po.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                          server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        
        # Prepare the stored procedure execution script
        storedProc = "exec usp_getproducts"
        
        # Execute Stored Procedure With Parameters
        cursor.execute(storedProc)
        
        # Iterate the cursor
        print(cursor.fetchone())
        print(1)
        
        # Close the cursor and delete it
        cursor.close()
        del cursor
        
        # Close the database connection
        cnxn.close()
```

This is the package files for pyodbc.

[image]

I have made the zip of above file and upload in Lambda function.

Please help-out what is the better way to deploy the python code in AWS lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned - "I have made the zip of above file and upload in Lambda function.". Did you created a layer using proper python version and added that layer in the above mentioned lambda function?

The error shows that it fails to locate the pyodbc package. Please read this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) for creating layer.

Keep one thing in mind, you have to first create a folder named "python" and then put all the files here pyodbc inside this python folder. Then zip the python folder and upload the zip file when creating the layer.

Comment: yes I have added the that zip file in layer also but also didn't work.  could you please send the pyodbc  package that's needs to be include with the steps.

Comment: I have edited my answer, added that python folder concept, please check and try